# How can I get a Makefile target to be called multiple times?

Tags: makefile

In the simple example below, I want to do a `make dist` and have the `distclean` target executed before `distdebug` *and* `distrelease`.

```
.PHONY: distclean

dist: distdebug distrelease
    @echo in dist

distdebug: distclean
    @echo in distdebug

distrelease:          
    @echo in distrelease

distclean:
    @echo in distclean
```

Unfortunately, despite using `.PHONY`, distclean is only called once:

```
vagrant@precise32:/tmp$ make dist
in distclean
in distdebug
in distrelease
in dist
```

I'm guessing that Make knows that its already run `distclean` once, so it's not running it again.  How can I make it run `distclean` multiple times?

Comment: Your question helped me do the opposite. I wanted `distclean` to be called exactly once in my case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't using normal rules.  Make will only ever build any given target exactly one time.  You can do it using recursive make invocations:

```
distdebug:
        $(MAKE) distclean
        @echo in distdebug
distrelease:
        $(MAKE) distclean
        @echo in distrelease
```

In general it's a good idea to plan your build differently, though, and have targets for different types of builds put into different subdirectories.  That way you don't HAVE to clean in between.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something similar, i.e. performing the same pattern (%) target more than once. And I don't like recursive make invocations. Anyway, I ended up in this solution:

```
run-%: build-%
    @echo "run-$(basename $*)"

build-%:
    @echo "build-$*"

build-%.2: build-%; @true
build-%.3: build-%; @true

run: run-foo run-foo.2 run-foo.3 run-bar
    @true
```

alternatively:

```
run: run-foo run-foo.2 run-bar run-foo.3
    @true

build-%:
    @echo "build-$*"

.SECONDEXPANSION:

run-%: build-$$(basename $$*)
    @echo "run-$(basename $*)"
```

This makefile can run-anything up to three times by adding the extensions .2 and .3 to anything, but it will only build anything once. I hope you get the idea.

```
> make run
build-foo
run-foo
run-foo
run-foo
build-bar
run-bar
```

Comment: With `.SECONDEXPANSION:` it is possible to get rid of any "extension" in a prerequisite and the above makefile can be both simplified and generalized, see the alternative above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursive make calls or enumerated rules. You can just using pattern matching to generate a different distclean alias for your debug and release steps:

```
.PHONY: dist%

dist: distdebug distrelease
    @echo in dist

distclean-%: # matches to distclean-debug, distclean-release etc 
    @echo in distclean

distdebug distrelease: dist% : distclean-% dist-% # clean first, then run

dist-debug:
    @echo in distdebug

dist-release:
    @echo in distrelease
```

So you can `make` and get:

```
in distclean
in distdebug
in distclean
in distrelease
in dist
```