# have GNU Make run a prerequisite target more than once

Tags: gnu-make

I'd would like a Make target to run for two prerequisite targets.

This example prints `a` once.  I would like to print `a` twice for target `foo`.

```
a:
   @echo 'hello from a'

foo: a bar
   @echo 'hello from foo'

bar: a
   @echo 'hello from bar'
```

`make foo` prints

```
hello from a
hello from bar
hello from foo
```

I would like `make foo` to print

```
hello from a
hello from a
hello from bar
hello from foo
```

Using *GNU Make 3.81*.

Comment: I believe this has been answered here [Call target multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730883/how-can-i-get-a-makefile-target-to-be-called-multiple-times)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a Makefile target to be called multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730883/how-can-i-get-a-makefile-target-to-be-called-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pattern rule to make separate "a" targets for foo and bar, like this:

```
a.%:
    @echo 'hello from a'

foo: a.foo bar
    @echo 'hello from foo'

bar: a.bar
    @echo 'hello from bar
```